# Retrofit. @Path для Headers

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Можно ли использовать @Path для замены части заголовка? К примеру можно ли сделать так:

```
@Headers("SomeString: {string}")
@GET("some/string")
Call<ResponseBody> getString(@Path("string") String str)
```

Comment: Нельзя, Path используется только для URL-адреса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать @HeaderMap
В данном случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
@GET("some/string")
Call<ResponseBody> getString(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> map)
```

Дальше в коде создаем Map и передаем туда нужные заголовки